# How to write array with index in Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

how can I write this line :

```
$value['description'][0]
```

in Smarty?

I tried to write it in this way :

```
{$value.description[0]}
```

But it's not working.

Comment: `{$value['description'][0]}`  http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.syntax.variables.tpl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This u need

```
{$value.description.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this on smarty

```
{foreach from=$value key=k item=v}
   <li>{$k}: {$v}</li>
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact you can do it either using dot operator:

```
{$value.description.0}
```

or using PHP-like syntax:

```
{$value['description'][0]}
```

Both will work.